# Update a Backbone view when model is saved

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following scenario -

```
window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/wines'

});
window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Wine,
   url: "/wines"
});
```

I have a model and the respective collection defined.

```
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#wineList',
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("add", function (wine) {
            alert("model added");
        });
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
            $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({
                model: wine
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
window.WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    initiliaze: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        var template = _.template($('#wine-list-item').html());
        $(this.el).html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

The above views creates an individual list item for each model.

```
window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#mainArea"),
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        var template = _.template($("#wine-details").html(), {});
        $(this.el).html(template);
    },
    events: {
        "click #save_form": "save_form"
    },
    save_form: function () {
        var wine = new Wine();
        wine.save();
        return false;
    }
});
window.HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.header',
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        var template = _.template($('#header').html());
        $(this.el).html(template());
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click .new": "newWine"
    },
    newWine: function (event) {
        var wine_View = new WineView();
        wine_View.render();
    }
});
```

In WineView, when the submit button of the form is clicked the model is saved. The Backbone.sync function is overridden.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list"
    },
    list: function () {
        this.wineList = new WineCollection();
        this.wineListView = new WineListView({
            model: this.wineList
        });
        this.wineList.fetch();
    }
});
var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
var header = new HeaderView();
```

My concern is, when the model is saved the WineListView doesn't get refreshed and show the new model that has been added. Precisely the this.mode.bind("add") doesn't get invoked.

I apologize for the verbosity of the question. But, this has been bothering me a for almost a week. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Could the typo "initiliaze" have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason add is never called is exactly that
once your wine is saved `wine.save();` you should add a success function and add it to the winelist collection

try this:

```
wine.save(wine.toJSON(), {
    success: function(){ 
        // model was saved successfully, now add it to the collection
        yourwinelist.add(wine);
        // if you can't access your wine list from this context, you might want to raise an event, and pass the wine, to catch it somewhere else:
        obj.trigger('myWineAdded', wine); // this can be raised on a global event aggregator
    },
    error: function(){ 
        // handle app when saving to server fails
        alert('failed to save wine');
    }
});
```

more info on the event aggregator idea check this :
[Routing and the event aggregator coordinating views in backbone.js](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you're never actually *adding* the new model to the collection. An easy way to do this, would be the collection's `create` method (assuming you have made the collection available):

```
save_form: function () {
    this.collection.create({ MODEL ATTRIBUTES HERE … });
    return false;
}
```

As the documentation states

> [t]he create method can accept either an attributes hash or an existing, unsaved model object.

Creating the new model like this, should trigger an `add` event **on the collection** if I'm not mistaken.

Another way, which — according to the docs should definitely trigger an `add` event (again, on the collection, not the model!)

```
save_form: function () {
    var wine = new Wine();
    this.collection.add(wine);
    return false;
}
```

> Add a model (or an array of models) to the collection. Fires an "add"
>   event, which you can pass {silent: true} to suppress.

In any case, remember to change your event binding:

```
this.collection.bind("add", function (wine) {
    alert("model added");
});
```